# Request a custom ant task from a private repository in a maven-antrun-plugin

Tags: maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

I am trying to execute a custom ant task, defined in a jar which is not under Maven Central, and thus I created a private repository for this.

The repository is defined with something like this, which hosts also other "private" jars, which are prefectly discovered:

```
  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.com</id>
            <name>repository.com</name>
            <url>http://repository.com/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

**Now the question**:

Although in the documentation states to define the dependency inside the <plugin> section only, I have found that I need to also define the dependency also inside the generic <dependencies> of the pom file.

So practically something like this, which duplicates the dependency descriptions:

```
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bitbucket.infinitekind</groupId>
            <artifactId>appbundler</artifactId>
            <version>1.0ea</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>local-install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <taskdef name="appbundler" onerror="fail" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.bitbucket.infinitekind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>appbundler</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0ea</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Is this the expected behaviour or I am missing something?

**EDIT**

It seems even then, the dependency is not fulfilled. 
Although I can clearly see that (due to the generic depenedency) the jar is downloaded and placed in ~/.m2 repository, ant task still doesn't understand it:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (local-install) on project cmmanager: Execution local-install of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.bitbucket.infinitekind:appbundler:jar:1.0ea in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 3):

Well, after some more digging, I found the answer. The problem is that plugin dependencies are resolved not through the repositories section, but through the pluginRepositories sections.
So this will fix the problem:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>repository.com</id>
        <url>http://repository.com/maven/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```